# Forcing ReSharper to use the red curly underline for some errors?

Tags: ide, compiler-errors, resharper

ReSharper defaults to using a red curly underline for some of its errors, and highlighting keywords red for others.  For the 'Cannot resolve symbol' error (which is the same as the 'The type or namespace name could not be found...' error in normal Visual Studio), ReSharper defaults to highlighting the unfound keyword red:

[image]

... instead of the default Visual Studio of using a red curly underline:

[image]

Is there a way to make ReSharper use a red curly underline instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually an error. The only different is that R# provides highlights it differently since it provides the option to create a type.

Alt+Shif+Page Down (or Page Up) to navigate between errors will actually identify this one and the error is even more evident if you enable the *Solution wide analysis* (bottom right corner) and open the *Errors in solution* window

[image: Cannot resolve symbol error]

Comment: I know it's an error, but I just don't prefer ReSharper's "red text" to a red underline.  :-)

Comment: Ooh. Ok. Sorry, I guess I misread this. I looked into Tools>Options>Environmnet>Fonts and Colors and found the *Display Items* used by ReSharper. You could change *ReSharper Error Highlight*. However, this option only lets you change foreground, background and font, so I don't see a way to add the red squiggly.